# Windows 10 Start Menu Items Disappeared?

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

A few days ago it seems as though most (seems like at least 50%) of my programs in the start menu have disappeared. I can't even search for them. I can, however, find each and every one of them through C:\Program Files (x64 and x86) so I know that they're still there.

When I look at the Start Menu > Programs dir (Users AppData and systems ProgramData) I also see all of my apps.

One weird thing is that I'm unable to open or right click any non-metro app. Metro apps start with no issues. Another weird thing is Edge tries to open with a blue metro screen but then fails to open at all. All this seems to be only on my account. My wife's account appears to be untouched. It seems like the start menu also sporadically stops wanting to open. This time it seems to have stopped opening after switching accounts to and back from my wife's account.

I'm currently doing a full disk backup just to make sure I don't lose any data. I ran full AV scan and it came back with nothing. I've restarted many times before now with no fix.

Anyone have any idea what might be the issue? I'll do a disk check in a moment once my backup completes and I'll update with that.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's one of those times where you finally get around to asking other people and then you get it fixed within 30 min of posting.

I'm not 100% sure what did it. But I think it may have been some sort of bug I may have gotten. It appears to have lived in temp files as I ran Disk Cleanup. After which I shut down my computer and when I got her back up all was well in the world.